# How can I speed up this Powershell Loop

Tags: powershell

I am very new at Powershell, but I recently decided to try and recreate an old tool we sometimes use but as a Powershell script. The script takes in user input to get an IP Range then pings, gets hostname, checks if service exists and is running, and then exports it to a CSV file. I haven't done too much cleaning up of the code yet. It does what I want but when I was testing it on larger IP ranges it was taking several minutes ie. 1-254 took around 10 minutes. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
Add-Content -Path ".\$fullrange.csv"  -Value '"Ping","IP","Hostname","Service State","Startup","Version"'

  ForEach($IP in $range) {
    $status = test-connection -computername ($IP) -count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($status) {
      $hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress("$IP")."HostName"
      $service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $IP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object Name -like "SysaidAgent"
      if ($service) {
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content "\\$IP\C$\Program Files\SysAid\Configuration\AgentConfigurationFile.xml")
        $ver = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//AgentVersion")."#text"
      }
      else{
        $service = "Not Found"
        $ver  = "N/A"
      }
      Add-Content -Path .\$fullrange.csv  -Value "$status,$IP,$hostname,$service.state,$service.startmode,$ver"
    }
    else{
      Add-Content -Path .\$fullrange.csv  -Value "$status,$IP"
    }
  }
```

Comment: `-TimeoutSeconds` is not a valid parameter with `Test-Connection`. Your script could be failing consistently due to a parameter error

Comment: My bad, that's not in the actual script. I was testing it in Powershell V6.0 where `-TimeoutSeconds` is a valid parameter. Looks like I forgot to remove it before posting here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Multithread PowerShell Ping Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954004/how-to-multithread-powershell-ping-script)

Comment: [2] think about replacing `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service` with `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Service` since the CIM stuff is usually faster.

Comment: [3] think about using `Get-Service -ComputerName $SysName -Name $ServiceName` since it is faster than either WMI or CIM calls from what i can tell.

Comment: [4] find some way to avoid reading that XML file across the net.